# MapView's onDestroy() causing UninitializedPropertyAccessException

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-android-api-2

I've got strange problem with Google Map's MapView component, which cause runtime exception UninitializedPropertyAccessException. **Exception is thrown after second configuration change (device rotation) in every other view except the one where MapView's method are overridden.** So, being in `MyMapViewFragment` which handles lifecycle of `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` this error is not thrown and configuration changes works fine.

Problem occurs in every other view, when I rotate the device `MyMapViewFragment.onDestroy()`  is invoked which destroys `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    googleMapView.onDestroy()
}
```

Rotating device second time causes UninitializedPropertyAccessException on `googleMapView.onDestroy()` line - MapView is not initliazed. Code of `MyMapViewFragment`:

```
class MyMapViewFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback {

   private lateinit var googleMapView: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
   private lateinit var googleMap : GoogleMap

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    var view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false)
    googleMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView2)
    googleMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    googleMapView.getMapAsync(this)
    bottomNavigationView = requireActivity().findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation)
    mountainCustomInfoWindow.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
    bottomNavigationView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    return view
 }

  override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap) {
    googleMap = map
  }
  override fun onPause() {
     super.onPause()
     googleMapView.onPause()
  }
  override fun onResume() {
     super.onResume()
     googleMapView.onResume()
  }
  override fun onDestroy() {
     super.onDestroy()
     googleMapView.onDestroy()
  }
  override fun onLowMemory() {
     super.onLowMemory()
     googleMapView.onLowMemory()
  }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
Process: com.hiker, PID: 25388
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {com.hiker/com.hiker.presentation.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property googleMapView has not been initialized
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4605)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4623)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4897)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1702)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
 Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property googleMapView has not been initialized
    at com.hiker.presentation.map.MapView.onDestroy(MapView.kt:173)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2830)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1028)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1310)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2644)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performDestroy(Fragment.java:2825)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1028)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2659)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2644)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchDestroy(FragmentController.java:329)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onDestroy(FragmentActivity.java:366)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onDestroy(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
    at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:7479)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1255)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:4592)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: Sure, added stacktrace to the question. I named ```com.hiker.presentation.map.MapView``` as ```MyMapViewFragment``` for clarity

Comment: Seems to me like `onDestroy` was called before `onCreateView` which is indeed odd. How are you adding the fragment to the activity?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, onCreateView is not invoked when configuration changes. I'm using Navigation Component with Navigation Graph and ```com.hiker.presentation.map.MapView``` is my starting view. In my MainActivity I have BottomNavigationView, which handles switching views

Comment: Cool, I just added an answer with another potential issue in addition. So you can accept it if you'd like

Answer (score 0):

More of a guess:
A property that is `lateinit` expects the property to be initialized before any other operation is done on it. We use that in this case, because we can only initialize it in `onCreateView` and not in a constructor. You are indeed initializing `googleMapView` on the second line of `onCreateView`.

But, you might actually not be initializing it properly if, `view.findViewById(R.id.mapView2)` would return `null`. Which is the case if no element with the id `mapView2` would be in the layout `fragment_map_view`. So verify there is actually a MapView there.

---

The other case that could happen is, if the Fragment wasn't actually attached to the View Hierarchy but was instantiated and registered in the Activity. When the Activity was destroyed, it destroyed the Fragment and called a method on the uninitialized object. *the actual case here*

(See the comments for the resolution).

Comment: I figured out that when I rotate device on TripView then this flow happens: MapView.onDestroy() -> MainActivity.onCreate() -> MapView.onCreate() -> TripView.onCreate(). Oddly, MapView.onCreate() is invoked, but why? This fragment doesn't have dependency with TripView. When I rotate the device second time then firstly MapView.onDestroy() and the application crashes..